# find text in string and replace it

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable which contains a string expression. This expression have the pattern:

`propery_expression operator value`

`proeprty_expression` can look like:

`World`
`World/Name`
`City/Name`

I want to find text after `/`, and If it exists, and replace with custom text. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regex, for example this one :

```
yourString.replace(/\/\S+/, '/the new stuff...');
```

In the console :

```
> var cityName = 'Djakarta';
> var line = 'World/Name Something SomethingElse';
> line.replace(/\/\S+/, '/' + cityName);
  "World/Djakarta Something SomethingElse"
```

You can use this to do complex search and replace operations. Details on [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: This regexp works well. But, if there are two `/` chars it's cut it. For example: `World/Country/City`. the result will be `World/_new_stuff_`, the `Country` is cut.

Comment: Sure. If you want a regexp that works perfectly for your dataset, we need do know exactly about the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
var the_string = "City/Name";
var word = "New";
var result = the_string.substring(0, the_string.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
alert(result + word);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var str = 'World';
alert(rep(str));


function rep(str)
{
    if(str.indexOf('/')>-1)//present
    {
        alert(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,str.length));
        var res = str.replace(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,str.length),'custom_word');
        return res;
    }
    else{
        alert(' / not present');
        return str;
    }
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hcY25/1/)

**Note:** If text present after `/` then it replace it with "custom_word".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mathias's answer, you could use RegEx together with a function, like so:

```
var myString;
.
.
.
myString.replace(/\/(\S+)/g, function (found, value) {
    // found == "City/NewYork"
    // value == "NewYork"
    return found + "Altered";
}
```

This, for example, will change every "x/y" with "x/yAltered"